# Python 3.7 with django 1.11

Tags: python, django

I've created a new Django project, when I run the server I get the error below:

```
from django.urls import path
ImportError: cannot import name 'path'
```

I seem to be running both Django 1.11 and 2.0, when I try create the folder in a virtual environment it installs Python 3.7 which sets Django 2.0 as the default. Is there a way around this?

Edit:

```
python -m venv venv --no-site-packages
```

Comment: Unistall djano, reactivate virtualenv, install django2

Comment: Python 3.7 was released recently, so Django 1.11 does not support it. You can either run Python 3.6 and Django 1.11, or Python 3.7 and Django 2.1. I wouldn't recommend running Django 2.0 since it will only be supported until Django 2.2 is released.

Answer (score 1):

When creating your virtual environment you can specify the version of packages you want to use. If you wanted to install django 1.11 you would use `pip install Django==1.11`. If you are starting from scratch I do not see why you wouldn't use the newest version of Django though.